# svn make a duplicate copy of file and rename it after committing a file

Tags: svn, svn-externals

My requirements are:

1. Let's say I commit a file called MyFile.item.
   After this, SVN should make a copy of this file to some other SVN location.
2. Once it is copied to another location it should also rename the file in new location as MyFile.java

Requirement 1, I think we can achieve this using **svn:externals** property.
Could someone help on how to automatically rename the files? Or any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an actual *copy* of the file in the repository, with divergent histories from the point at which you copied forward, that would be a job for a post-commit hook script. But I would also ask you to take a *very* hard look at your processes and reconsider this, because it's wasteful, confusing, and has a good chance of breakage.

If you need a "virtual copy" of the file, in which you can modify the file in either location and the modification will appear in both places, you want a [file-level external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html). On the directory which will host the copy, set the `svn:externals` property with the URL to the "real" file and the new name that you want in that directory.

```
svn propset svn:externals DIRECTORY http://URL_TO_YourFile.java MyFile.java
```